# Pan sharpening in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pansharpening

I was wondering if anyone has successfully been able to perform an image pan sharpening within QGIS?  I have utilized OpenEV to do this, but the results have been very pixelated.

Any info would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that the ORFEO Tool Box has some handy pansharpening tools which should, in theory, be available via the SEXTANT plugin. I have not gone this route so I might be wrong. Check it out and see what you can find.

Comment: I did read that.  I have Sextant installed on my Windows 7 machine, and I do not see any option for ORFEO Toolbox.  I am installing Ubuntu on my machine to see if it will be available on Ubuntu.  From what I saw, it looked like the toolbox was available from Ubuntu.