# Merge and export two layers that utilize blending modes

Tags: qgis, layers, export, pansharpening, composite

I have spent more time than I can to admit trying to come up with a solution that doesn't require bringing the layers into Photoshop or the GIMP (which would take an insane amount of RAM/swap space to work on this).

Here's the setup:
Using QGIS 2.8.1 on Ubuntu.  2 layers imported, both have srs and align properly.

Layer 1: Low resolution color imagery for the entire planet
Layer 2: Higher resolution B&W imagery for an entire planet

I'm using the color information from Layer 1 and overlaying it on the higher resolution B&W imagery of layer 2.  To do this, I use the following:

Layer one: Properties: Color rendering: Blending mode: Hard Light
Layer two: Properties: Band rendering: Contrast Enhancement: No enhancement
Layer two: Properties: Color rendering: Contrast: -15

After setting these values, the resultant two datasets look very good over one another.

Now, my issues as I see them:

1. I need to merge the two layers into one
2. I need to export the resultant merged layer into a geotiff

I can figure out #2 okay using layer: Save As: Output mode: Rendered Image, etc

But, what I cannot figure out is #1.

Comment: Effectively you're trying to pan-sharpen the imagery https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pansharpened_image. Is that correct? Have a look at this post http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53080/pansharpening-in-qgis or a better one http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63367/how-to-pansharpen-landsat-8-in-grass

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in that direction.  Not being GIS by trade, some of these keywords don't jump out at me to know to search.  The links and the term pansharpening were very helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try exporting the whole project with extent and pixel size=resolution set to match the input files:

```
qgis --project myproject.qgs --snapshot image.png --width 1500 --height 1000 --extent xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax
```

cf. http://anitagraser.com/2010/11/30/creating-high-resolution-images-using-qgis/

edit: that's comparable to *Project->Save As Image* (creates a world file) but allows to specify extent and size manually

Comment: That did it.  I have to tweak some of the settings, but it should be perfect for this need.